# Join several child records in parent database search

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables, subquery

I have the following tables:

`Client` and `Companies`. A `Client` can have multiple `Companies`. I am currently displaying the list of `Clients` in a [jQuery dataTable](https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side) using server-side processing. Everything works fine, but the people using it have asked me if they could also search using some company names as the search criteria.

Now, under normal circumstances, dataTable does that on its own searching the fields. But dataTable seriously slows down after a couple of hundred entries, so I am forced to use with server-side processing, and I have to do the search and  handle the end results, dataTable being responsible only to display the current lot.

I am currently doing a `LIKE` comparison on several of the `Clients` table fields for search.

What I was thinking is that I might add a concatenated list of all the `Companies` belonging to the each `Client` and add the custom field to the `LIKE` comparisons, and even might display it as a small list after the client's name.

What could I do in this case, is the idea I am having possible or is there some better way to do this?

I thought maybe some sort of subquery, but it should return only one result.

**UPDATE: Database structure**

**Clients**

- client_id | INT(11) | NOT NULL | AUTO_INCREMENT
- first_name | VARCHAR(200) | NOT NULL
- last_name | VARCHAR(200)
- email | VARCHAR(200) | NOT NULL
- password | TEXT
- phone | VARCHAR(50)
- birth_date | DATE
- registration_date | DATETIME
- client_type | INT(11) - References `ClientTypes` table
- status_id | INT(11) | NOT NULL - References `ClientStatus` table

**Companies**

- company_id | INT(11) | NOT NULL | AUTO_INCREMENT
- company_name | VARCHAR(200) | NOT NULL
- company_name_slug | VARCHAR(200) | NOT NULL
- created_on | DATETIME | NOT NULL
- updated_on | DATETIME
- client_id | INT(11) | NOT NULL - References `Clients` table

I can't copy the exact `CREATE` statements because the real tables have several more fields and relations with other tables. I added a resumed version, but the idea is there. I am expecting to be able to do something like:

**End Result in DataTable cell**

Client Alpha

- Company Foo
- Company Bar
- Company Omega

Client Beta

- Company Omega

Client Gamma

- Company Foo

And if I search for "**omega**" I want the result to contain Clients Alpha and Beta.

Comment: Show the table structures (as text - `SHOW CREATE TABLE Client` +`Companies`) and server side code? What do you expect your SQL results to be for a query?

Comment: @danblack I added more details on the database. Unfortunately the `SHOW CREATE` is not really an option as the tables have several relations and a bunch more fields, but I think the description is better now.

Comment: So a query like: `SELECT Clients.* FROM Clients JOIN Companies USING (client_id) WHERE company_name LIKE '%omega%'` with appropriate SQL injection prevention and selecting the needed fields.

Comment: That was probably the easiest solution :) worst part is I have several similar uses, but I didn't think using it like that. I actually had to change `USING` for `ON`, but otherwise it worked. You can post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a query with a JOIN like:

```
SELECT Clients.* FROM Clients
JOIN Companies ON Companies.client_id = Clients.client_id
WHERE company_name LIKE '%omega%'
```

With appropriate SQL injection prevention and selecting the needed fields.